Modelling overlapping time periods
I have been tracking my weight and calorie intake over a large period of time. Let's say I have 100 sequential days of complete calorie observations.
I can estimate things like total daily energy expenditure (TDEE) by regressing weight on calories. The widely accepted figure is 3,500 kcal of deficit leads to 1 lb of weight loss (or 1,600-kcal deficit for 1 kg of loss).
Now, I could model the entire 100-day period, but I am also interested in investigating shorter timespans within that. The easiest thing to do would be to split up the 100 days into 7 two-week periods. However, you could split 100 days into many more overlapping two-week periods, each with a value of (total calories) and (total loss).
Of course, these new periods wouldn't be independent, but multiplying the number of periods would give me a lot more power, but I'm unclear on how to approach this problem, I can't find anything because I don't know what to call it.
